# About action memoryStream

Tags: c#

I find this code on internet and dont understand how server can send full size for client and why client can know file size. Help me response :(

```
Code server: 
FileStream fs = null;
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(textBox4.Text);
ulong fileSize = (ulong)fi.Length; 
byte[] buf = new byte[32 * 1024]; 
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buf);//
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(ms);
bw.Write(fileSize);
fs = File.OpenRead(textBox4.Text); 
int ns = socket.Send(buf, sizeof(ulong), SocketFlags.None);//why only 32KB which client 
                                                       //can know file size  
ulong pos = 0;
while (pos < fileSize) 
{   int nr = fs.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    if (nr <= 0) { break; } 
    pos += (ulong)nr;
    ns = socket.Send(buf, nr, SocketFlags.None); 
}
```

Code client:

```
FileStream fs = null; 
fs = File.Create(saveFileName); 
byte[] buf = new byte[32 * 1024]; 
int nr = socket.Receive(buf, sizeof(ulong), SocketFlags.None); 
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buf); 
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms); 
ulong fileSize = br.ReadUInt64(); 
ulong pos = 0; 
while (pos < fileSize)
{      nr = socket.Receive(buf);
   if (nr <= 0) { throw new Exception("Receive 0 byte"); } 
   pos += (ulong)nr; 
   fs.Write(buf, 0, nr); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The server first writes this:

```
bw.Write(fileSize);
```

The client first reads this:

```
ulong fileSize = br.ReadUInt64();
```

Ergo, the client knows how many bytes are to follow.

Comment: Thank :). buf send several times or only one time @Moo-Juice

Comment: @ThanhBình not sure what you mean - in the example code you pasted above, the server sends the size of the file, then the entire file itself.  The client reads the length and then subsequently reads until it has read enough bytes (or something goes wrong and the exception is thrown).

Comment: int ns = socket.Send(buf, sizeof(ulong),SocketFlags.None); i want know size buf is over 32kb this line code and socket send multiple times for client know size file? sorry, my english is bad :)